# Single Org : Org vs Packaged Development Model for Greenfield Project

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, deployment, scratch-org, unmanaged-package

We are going to start a new greenfield project and we have identified that we will have single org model deployed with multiple apps built on it for different business units in organisation. One of the benefit we would want to deliver as part of this is to have independent release for functionality between these different apps. Currently our implementation partner and CSA involved seems to be telling us that 'package development model' is not an established development model. Also, DevOps automation tool like Copado and Flosum doesn't seem to support package development model yet. We are expecting partner teams to deploy real developers with GIT, CLI etc skills and in-house we have developers who are quite aware of GIT,CLI-centric skills.

Can I get some understanding of the pros, cons and limitations of package development model ? and is Salesforce not confident on package development model from future point of view and they can possibly stop supporting it ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. This question is rather opinion based so doesn't really fit with the site, and is likely to be closed without answer. That said, anyone saying package development is not a well established approach is quite wrong and likely is saying this because they don't have the experience or knowledge.

Comment: BTW I strongly recommend use of 2GP, unlocked packages and can say that Salesforce recommend a "mono repository" approach, though having different development cycles for different packages suggests a repository per package.

Comment: Thank you @PhilW for your response and your response do give me an understanding of the rationale of my partner team response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is a large question that is in part opinion-based, I think there are some factual elements we can address quite directly.

> Currently our implementation partner and CSA involved seems to be telling us that 'package development model' is not an established development model.

I disagree strongly with this claim. The package development model is well-defined and established. It's documented both on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_dev_model) and elsewhere. Second-generation packaging and unlocked packaging are growing models that are undergoing continual enhancement and offering new features.

Packaging does not solve all problems of development on the Salesforce platform, and it's not perfect in and of itself. However, it does come with really significant benefits that should not be discounted, including the ability to create modular, independent components of your overall implementation that can be separately versioned, upgraded, and potentially distributed across multiple Salesforce orgs.

If you're working on a large enterprise project with multiple teams operating independently, building your application as independent packaged modules that can be iterated and tested separately in scratch orgs *may* permit you to significantly increase your velocity and reduce your dependence on a shared pipeline of persistent orgs. That said, it's important to emphasize again that packaging is not a silver bullet and your use case, compliance regime, and team capabilities will dramatically influence the development strategy and pipeline you ultimately adopt.

> Also, DevOps automation tool like Copado and Flosum doesn't seem to support package development model yet.

*Disclaimer: I haven't used Copado or Flosum hands-on*.

Some of the work done by commercial DevOps tools is handled by the platform when you use the package development model.

DevOps tools provide a wide slate of capabilities but usually center on moving specific changes between environments. When your development is done in packages, the shape of those processes change: you make decisions about what changes get promoted by when you merge code and cut package versions, and you handle the promotion itself by installing new package versions. You still need process, of course, but you reduce your need for off-platform tooling to handle tasks like moving metadata - that's part of packaging.

> is Salesforce not confident on package development model from future point of view and they can possibly stop supporting it ?

I am a Salesforce employee, but I am not part of the packaging teams. This statement is not based on any proprietary or non-public information.

I would be astonished if that were to come to pass. Package development using unlocked or second-generation packages and scratch orgs is a major enhancement to development on the Salesforce platform over the last several years that converges the platform closer to norms of other technology stacks.

---

None of these statements bears upon the question *is the package development model right for your org and your project?*

That question only you and your partners, ultimately, can answer. However, I do think it's important to do so with a fuller awareness of the key benefits of packaging and without incorrect claims about its viability.

Comment: Thank you David for your detailed response. It is quite clear that package development is way-forward for establishing modular development approach but I might need to work more closely with partner teams to define an approach in which we can adopt this while there are some risks involved in adopting this approach in a large organisation.

Comment: I would say this actually and actively reduces risk for large orgs.